# What's $(MAKE) or ${MAKE} actually supposed to mean in make scripting language

Tags: compiling, make, gnu

What's  `$(MAKE)` or `${MAKE}` actually performing in entire `make` building process.
is it invoking a process which is similar to sub-routine i.e. in simplest terms 'call a function', or is it starting a recursive process to the beginning of its own file ?

Answer (score 1):

The `make` program sets a variable `MAKE` which could be used in makefiles as `$(MAKE)` or `${MAKE}`.  The latter is useful because shell scripts recognize that syntax, and it is possible to reuse some scraps of script between the two.

There's not much overlap between shell/make syntax aside from that, since `make` treats things like `$$` differently from shell.

Addressing the point of the question: the `MAKE` variable helps with recursion since the program may not actually be named **`make`** (e.g., `gmake`, `pmake`), and you need that bit of information to successfully recur in the same program.  The `make` program (however it is (re)named)) recognizes that recursion whether the variable is used or not.

Further reading: [POSIX make](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html)

Answer (score -1):

`$(MAKE)` contains a path to the current make program unless you overwrite it.

If you just call `make` or the name of your make implementation, `$(MAKE)` should contain just that name, since your make implementation was then called via `PATH` search. Check this by e.g. calling:

```
cd /usr/bin
./make -f /dev/null | grep MAKE
```

If you call your make implementation via an absolute or relative path, `$(MAKE)` contains the absolute path name to your make implementation.

This allows you to use `$(MAKE)` in your make files in a way that grants you that you will always call the same make program even in case this is a temporary binary compiled with debug messages and installed anywhere.

BTW: You may get the initial value set up by your make program by calling:

```
$make -f /dev/null -p | grep MAKE
```